# How to utilize network for p2p file sharing on Android Platform?

Tags: android, networking, p2p

I'm working on some apps for the android platform and I have two problems that I'm not quite sure how to approach, and both are closely related.

1. How can I send a relatively small data file from one android device to another (preferably over the internet or directly through wireless network)?
2. Is it possible to create a temporary p2p live data stream from one android device to another?  An example application would be to stream low-res video from phone A's camera to phone B, or audio.

I would much appreciate being pointed in the right direction on either issue (File transfer or real time data transfer).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get Google's library [libjingle](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html) to work on Android. It provides quite advanced NAT Traversal capabilities, which should be able to get through the carriers' firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the socket classes in [java.net](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/java/net/package-summary.html).

Comment: This method won't work, because it does not solve NAT traversal.

Answer (score 0):

To use WiFi to send data among devices, you can try to establish an ad-hoc network among the devices that will communicate. I think you can use Android's WiFi API to do that. Once you have the ad-hoc network setup, you can establish a simple TCP connection between the devices and transfer the files.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets do not work between phones. I've tried with two actual phones using socket communications and there seems to be a firewall in the carriers that prevents communications on ports different than port 80. Then if you try to use port 80 you get a 'Permission Denied' exception.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to investigate the [JXTA](http://jxse.kenai.com) framework. The Practical JXTA II book is available online for reading at Scribd.